# Очередь потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность, потоки-данных

1. Два потока должны выводить по очереди слова из предложения.
2. Алфавит. Один поток выводит на консоль гласные буквы, другой согласные.
    Подскажите, пожалуйста, как этого добиться... Вот, что у меня пока что есть:

   ```
   public class ThreadOfWords extends Thread{
       public ThreadOfWords(String str){
           super();
           setName(str);
       }

       public synchronized void run(){
           String [] mas1 = {"My", "is", "I", "java."};
           String [] mas2 = {"name", "Leyla.", "like", ":)"};
           String [] mas3 = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};
           String [] mas4 = {"b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l",      "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"};
           String nameT = getName();

           if("First".equals(nameT)){
               for(int i = 0; i < mas1.length; i++){
                   System.out.println(mas1[i]);
                   try{
                       Thread.sleep(200);
                   } catch(InterruptedException e){
                       System.out.println(nameT + "прерван");
                   }
               }
           } else if("Second".equals(nameT)){
               for(int i = 0; i < mas2.length; i++){
                   System.out.println(mas2[i]);
                   try{
                       Thread.sleep(200);
                   } catch(InterruptedException e){
                       System.out.println(nameT + "прерван");
                   }
               }
           } else if("Third".equals(nameT)){
               for(int i = 0; i < mas3.length; i++){
                   System.out.println(mas3[i]);
                   try{
                       Thread.sleep(500);
                   } catch(InterruptedException e){
                       System.out.println(nameT + "прерван");
                   }
               }
           } else if("Fourth".equals(nameT)){
               for(int i = 0; i < mas4.length; i++){
                   System.out.println(mas4[i]);
                   try{
                       Thread.sleep(500);
                   } catch(InterruptedException e){
                       System.out.println(nameT + "прерван");
                   }
               }
           }       
       }
   }

   public class Words {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ThreadOfWords tr1 = new ThreadOfWords("First");
       ThreadOfWords tr2 = new ThreadOfWords("Second");

       tr1.setPriority(10);
       tr2.setPriority(1);

       tr1.start();
       tr2.start();                
    }
   }

   public class ABC {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ThreadOfWords tr1 = new ThreadOfWords("Third");
       ThreadOfWords tr2 = new ThreadOfWords("Fourth");

       tr1.setPriority(10);
       tr2.setPriority(1);

       tr1.start();
       tr2.start();
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Играться приоритетами и таймером в таких задачах - это последнее дело.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте действовать так (псевдокод):

1. Заведите два семафора: для гласных и для согласных. Вначале заприте семафор для согласных и отоприте для согласных.
2. Поток, который выдаёт гласные, работает так. Он пытается запереть семафор для гласных. Когда он получает свой семафор, он выводит одну гласную, отпирает семафор для согласных и начинает цикл сначала.
3. Поток, который выдаёт согласные, работает симметрично. Он пытается запереть семафор для согласных. Когда он получает свой семафор, он выводит одну согласную, отпирает семафор для гласных и начинает цикл сначала.
4. По окончанию данных (все гласные или согласные выведены) поток должен взвести соответствующий флаг, который разрешит другому потоку не синхронизироваться, а вывести остаток информации без пауз.

---

Это будет работать так. Сначала «поток гласных» ждёт, т. к. его семафор заперт. «Поток согласных» успешно запирает семафор, выводит согласную, отпирает семафор гласных (другой поток начинает работу), и пытается снова запереть свой семафор. Поскольку его семафор заперт, он будет ждать до тех пор, пока «поток гласных» не закончит свою итерацию.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем разносить по потокам если они по порядку должны выполняться? Просто поиграться?

Comment: (задание на курсах)